# Giving a result with a sub query and a formula?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have this issue that is going around my head lately, I wanna know how many of my users can have more than a 50% of profit in their accounts. So, as you can see in the table, I have investment and earnings, so logically I must do a percentage for having the profit. Like: ((earnings - investment * 100) / investment)

```
ID  Investment (euros)  Earnings (euros)
13      2   3.4
14      1   0
15      4   7
16      12  20.76
```

From here everything is ok, but my question is, how can I calculate and show at the same time the users that have more than a 50% of profit?

I made this simple query that works but don't shows the users that have more than 50%, shows everyone.

```
select id, ((MAX(earnings)-investment)*100)/investment
from users
group by id, investment
;
```

So, my idea was to create a subquery, but I have a great issue with this:

```
select id
from users
where 50 < (
select (((MAX(earnings)-investment)*100)/investment)
from users
group by investment
)
group by id
;
```

I received this error:
Detail: Expected no more than one row to be returned by expression

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Jalp!

Comment: How is a user defined in your table?  I would expect one row per user (in a table called `users`), so no aggregation would be necessary.

Comment: well, in the table you have id (int 8), investment (numeric), earnings (numeric).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this the formula?

```
select id, (sum(earnings) - sum(investment))*100 / sum(investment) as profit
from users
group by id;
```

Then if you want to filter, add:

```
having profit > 50
```

To get the count, use a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select id, (sum(earnings) - sum(investment))*100 / sum(investment) as profit
      from users
      group by id
     ) u
where profit > 50;
```

Comment: Sorry sir! but it works perfectly after trying the subquery! impresive, I didn't know I needed to call it as a form for make it work this kind of querys, but the only bad thing is when I try the having and call the alias "profit" don't accept it, I used the sub query as you said for it